# Implementing multiple overloaded functions vs doing inside checking/validation for enforcing business logic

Tags: oop, software-design

This is a general issue, but i will demonstrate it using the following problem:

I want to model airCrafts. now, for every aircraft there is one capability that is loaded with: attackCapability, IntelligenceCapability and BdaCapability. Not all aircraft can be loaded with all capabilities - every airCraft has its own potential capabilities that is supports and can be loaded with.

I want to implement this business logic with composition:
every aircraft object will hold a private member of type Capability (every capability will be implemented by a class that inherits from this abstract class/interface).

Now - I want to design a code that will enforce the business logic - i.e. will not allow any programmer to load an aircraft with an ability it doesn't support.

I have two options for doing this:

1. implement several overloaded version of the `SetCapability()` function - each one with the type of capability i want to support. For example:

```
public void SetCapability(AttackCapability capability);
public void SetCapability(BdaCapability capability);
```

That way the user can't load the aircraft with forbidden capability - and if he/she will try doing so, there will be a compilation erorr - i.e. that IDE will show some error message.

2. implement one function: public void SetCapability(Capability capability)
   and doing some checking inside it. something like this:

```
public void SetCapability(Capability capability){
    if(capability.getType() != typeOf(AttackCapability) || capability.getType() != typeOf(BdaCapability){
           throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }
    _capability = capability;
}
```

the disdvantage here is that misuse of the user will be identified only at runtime instead at compiletime (much harder to identify and more bug prone), but as opposed to the previous option - it doesn't make you write several overloaded function which may cause the class to look heavy, strange and less readable for the inexperienced programmer.
(code reusability is not a big issues, because we always can implement private function like: private void SetCapabiltiy(Capability capability); which do the setting logic and every public overloaded SetCapability function will call it).

I feel that both option have their advantages and disadvantages as i described above.

I tend to prefer the first one, because it is more safe and hermeric - but it frequently causes my code to look "ugly" and some programmers may interprete it as duplicated code and don't understand the point...

I would like to hear your opinion for this issues, and maybe you have some better designs for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't understand your #1 option, but I think in any option you said you need to check permitted capabilities statically. This would result to change the code in future and would break the `OCP`. Instead of this I thought that maybe we can take advantage of dynamic dispatch here and let it to check types.

IMHO you can create final concrete classes and set required access modifiers to private in the concretes and then use factories(actually the `abstract factory` pattern looks suitable here) to hide object creation from clients to enforce business logic and the use the technique(which is my term) that referencing the same type used in `Decorator` or `Chain of Responsibility` patterns to keep capabilities in a chain by which you may have extra possibilities to dynamically check the capabilities to apply the behavior they require instead of just in a list( which could be used with `Command pattern` also)

As a note, the section where you mention as your second option limits the extensibility and generally manual type check is considered as bad practice in a dynamically dispatched or duck typed OOP language runtime. I know the fact that you are checking the field not a type but this is also a manual control and capability as the name implies is a behavior not state.

Finally since the aircrafts don't have same functionalities, but varying behaviors `Visitor` pattern could be used to design functionalities by which you create method classes instead of classes containing methods.

In addition, a `Map<Aircraft, List<Capability>>` could be used by keeping in a config object chek the features when creating objects by using DI.

```java
//Capability types
interface Capable {
   do();
}

class Attacker implements Capable {
   private Capable capability;

   public Attacker(Capable capability) { //to keep track of next/linked capability
      this.capability = capability;
   }

   public do(String request) {
     this.attack();
     this.capability.do();//or instead of this decorator you could use chain of responsibility with next() and handle() below.
   }   
   
   //to select features in some functionality.
   public handle(String request) {
     if ("attack".equals(request)) { //just to show what you can by keeping a reference to same type
        this.attack();
     } else {
        this.capability.do();
     }
   }
   
   public next(Capable capability) {
      this.capability = capability;
   }
}

class Intelligent implements Capable {
   //similar to above.
}

//Aircraft types
class F111 implements Aircraft {
   private Capable capability;
   //or store capabilities in a list and check with config mapper object(maps aircrafts with its capabilities in a Map<Aircraft.TYPE, List<Capable> capabilities)
   //private List<Capable> capabilities;

   //other state
   Aircraft(Capable capability) { //or create a factory
      this.capability = capability;
   }
   
   //behaviors
   doSth() {
      this.capability.do();
   }
   
}

class F222 implements Aircraft {
   //...
}

//To hide creation of requested aircraft with only its required capabilities from the client
static class AircraftFactory { //dont permit to directly access to Aircraft concretes
    static Aircraft getAircraft(String type) {//could be used abstract factory instead of this.
       if("f111".equals(type)) {
          return new F111(new Attacker(new Intelligent()));
       } 
       else if(...) { new F222(new Intelligent(new Bda())}
       else if(...) { new F001(new Default()) }
    }
}

class Client {
   main() {
      //instead of this
      //Aircraft f9999 = new Aircraft(new Attacker);
      //f9999.doSth();
      
      //enforce client to use factory.
      Aircraft aircraft = AircraftFactory.getAircraft("f222");
      aircraft.doSth();
   }
}
```